# Stop box from breaking to next line due to extra margin?

Tags: html, css, margin

Not sure if this is even possible, but I think it's worth asking.

What I am trying to do is have boxes created via my PHP script with ease, where I don't have to check which column, row, etc. each box (.boxes) belongs to. I just want to be able to do a foreach loop of the boxes, and `echo` them.

Here's what I am talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/LUFFP/4/

In that example, you can see that I am trying to get the `wrapper` (#main) to ignore the `margin-right`, and have two boxes per row, with no extra space on the right, without having to assign different classes to every other DIV.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `nth-of-type(2n)` to target every other div. Then set the right margin to zero.

http://jsfiddle.net/LUFFP/5/

```
.boxes_3:nth-of-type(2n) { margin-right: 0px; }
```

Comment: See this article if you are interested in why you may choose `nth-of-type` vs `nth-child` as in Danjah's answer. http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-nth-child-and-nth-of-type/

Comment: +1 for nth-of-type voodoo that I can never seem to get straight.  Plus, it's a lot cleaner/less hackish than my answer, if you're willing to omit support for a few browsers about which nobody cares.

Comment: oooh there's some voodoo there indeed - good tip, thanks @mrtsherman :)

Comment: Doh, edit timer's up - I re-read that article to see where I was awry: I incorrectly assumed that the "p:" part of the selector did what that article explains about nth-type-of.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your browser requirements, there's a CSS3 selector to do that:
http://jsfiddle.net/ttpK6/1/

Compatability list here: http://kimblim.dk/css-tests/selectors/

Answer (score 1):

```
#main_2
{
    background: #FF0000;
    width: 404px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.boxes_2
{
    background: #F3F3F3;
    width: 195px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Notice that I changed the width and set overflow to hidden.  No special CSS3 requirements.

Comment: +1 - I like it Zen. Way to think 'out of the box.' Pun intended.

Comment: @mrtsherman Haha, why thank you.  Yes, I guess it is still a bit outside the box, isn't it?  Overflowing margins never hurt anyone.

Comment: Not sure what browser you use, but it doesn't work on the latest Google Chrome for me. I originally tried this (`overflow: hidden;`), to no result. http://jsfiddle.net/LUFFP/7/ http://cloud.rastalulz.com/1U0G2n2y1i1j0I2l2f25

Comment: @JoshFoskett You have to set the width, too.  Works for me in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
 #main_2 {background: #FF0000; width: 411px;  border: 1px solid #000;}
.boxes_2 {background: #F3F3F3; width: 205px;  float:left;}
```

Comment: You can code block your post by prepending each line with four spaces or by using the `{}` button in the editor.

Comment: If you add `overflow: hidden`, the red will go away, provided you change the width to 404px.